# Binary numbers with the same quantity of 0s and 1s

Tags: algorithm, math

When I was solving [Euler project problem #15](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=15) I realized that it can be solved with the # of combinations of ways of the route from start to end. The route generated always has the same size of right or down choices (or 0s and 1s) and the right routes always have the same qty of 0s and 1s.
So qty of numbers with the same qty of 0s and 1s in a binary word are 
C(2,1) for 1bit length
C(4,2) for 2bit "    "
C(6,3) for 4bit "    "
...

Now comes my questions:
Is there a function that solves if a number has the same qty of 0s and 1s? 
I guess that it would be more like a logical function, I don't want to iterate all the digits or use regex (that would be worse than iterate).

**Other question is about the growth and the space between this "balanced" values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a follow up to Paul R's answer, there **is** a simplification of the formula for the central binomial coefficient, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html

p = n! / ((n/2)!)² = 2<sup>n/2</sup> (n-1)!! / (n/2)!

k!! is the "double factorial", which means you skip every other number when calculating: k!! = k * (k-2) * (k-4) * ...  (as long as the factor is positive).

For your calculation a lot of numbers will cancel out (you can use the gcd for this when calculating numerator and denominator simultaneously)

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a *popcount* function, which counts the number of set bits in a given number. Some processors have it builtin, some don't.

```
c=0; while (n &= (n-1)) c++;
```

does the job, but destroys `n`.

See [this link](http://wiki.cs.pdx.edu/forge/popcount.html) for better algorithms, or google "popcount".

Comment: You won't really want to brute force this by iterating through all possible numbers and testing the population count - it really is the inverse operation that we're looking for.

Comment: @Paul R: Quoting OP: "Is there a function that solves if a number has the same qty of 0s and 1s?", I think I answered the question. If the question is wrong, it is OP's problem.

Comment: @Alexandre: you're right - too late to remove the -1 though - sorry.

Comment: Actually it's never late to remove it, and I guess you should more carefully read answer before downvote it, there is no one even tried to iterate over all numbers. only gave a way to check. after all there is someone thinks that P != NP, hence search not equal to identification ;)

Comment: @Artem: how do you remove a vote after it's more than 5 minutes old ?

Comment: Well I didn't knew about popcount instruction, this is really useful for this problem, thanks for that. About the inverse I thought about it and there's problems like the plenty of the sequences that have left 0s and evaluate, so I can't figure a way to evaluate a inverse.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly then you just what `p = nCr` where `r = n/2`. So:

`p = n! / ((n/2)! * (n/2)!)`

Comment: this is likely to overflow. A proper way to compute binomial coefficient is by computing log(C(n,k)) with the help of loggamma.

Comment: 6C3 = 20 and not 3!=6. I think you have confused a bit.

Comment: @Artem: yes, my attempt to simplify the expression introduced an error - I've edited the answer now as there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to simplify.

Comment: If the resulting answer doesn't overflow, Binomial Coeff. can be Calculated using the Prime Factorization Method (without overflowing)

Answer (score 0):

The balanced values can be found directly by imagining that you're picking your path along the way (i.e. choose to go up `n` times out of `2n`).

There are, therefore, `C(2n,n)` of those values, which is `2n! / (n! * n!)`.  The total number of values is, of course, `2^2n`.  Using Stirling's approximation, we find

```
ln n! ~= n ln n - n + ln(2*pi*n)/2
ln 2n!/(n!*n!) = ln(2n!) - 2*ln(n!) ~= 2n*ln(2) - n + ln(4*pi*n)/2 - ln(2*pi*n)
```

so that the fraction of values which are good, `C(2n,n)/2^(2n)` is

```
exp(2n*ln(2) - n + ln(4*pi*n)/2 - ln(2*pi*n) - 2n*ln(2)) =
exp(-n)/sqrt(pi*n)
```

so the number of good values decrease exponentially.

This is why it's wise to just pick them out directly instead of test.

But if you really want to test, there are various bit-counting methods [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan).  (Kernighan's is probably the fastest--note however that he wasn't the first person to notice it, and that an equivalent algorithm is already posted here!)

Comment: Yep, I found Kernighan's method included in that popcount list, thanks for the explanation about the decrease of good values. I started a graphics of values from 2^2 .. 2^10 centered, after that only the center values (till 2^16) appears in a 2^10 width graphic.
http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/6369/distribuicao.png

Answer (score 0):

You could use a look-up table mapping an n-bt number to its 1-count. For example, if you always had 23-bit unsigned integers a lookup table of 16 bits and 7 bits would allow you to split the number and add the one-count from the lookup tables for the 16 and 7 bit portions. (The 7-bit look-up table could be just a section of the 16 bit table).

Comment: well, I don't know if I understand it right. But only to fill the table costs at least O(n), I guess that ain't better way than popcount to do this

Answer (score 0):

For an even value of 'i', the number of such numbers(equal 1's and 0's) between 2^i and 2^(i-1) are given by the following formula:

(i-1)!/[x! * (x-1)!]

where x=i/2.

I tried writing a program in C for generating this, but it overflowed. Then I did it using floating point arithmetic. Till i=56 its good. After that the accuracy decreases.

But BigInt libraries should be able to do this task without overflow.

Comment: I can find the how many numbers with the same quantity of 0s and 1s with a combination. The values one the central column of pascal triangle are that same values the first answer simplifies the formula. What I needed to know if is there a logical function to gives me true or false if that number is one of those. Popcount is the most close to the best solution that I found. With that I can found if that number has the same qty on O(1).