# Bit count for all numbers up to 1048576 is wrong

Tags: c

I want to convert all integers below 1048576 to binary and display all numbers which have the same number of bits set as unset. My program works fine when I use a table `t` of 20 integers, in which case `cpt` records the correct result.

However, when I use a table `t` of 40 integers (which means I want the numbers with 20 '1' bits and 20 '0' bits) the counter is set to 1. What is wrong?

```
int main(){        
    long int a;
    int r,j,i;
    long int aux;
    int z,u;
    long int cpt;
    int t[40];
    for(int k=0;k<40;k++) t[k]=0;
    cpt=0;

    for(a=0;a<1048576;a++){
        j=0;u=0;z=0;
        aux=a;
        do{
            r=aux%2;                  
            switch(r){
            case 0 : t[j]=0;
                aux=(aux/2);
                j++; 
                break;                  
            case 1 : t[j]=1;
                aux=((aux-1)/2);
                j++;
                break;
            }

        }while(aux!=0);

        for(i=0;i<40;i++){
            if(t[i]==0) z++;
            else u++;
        }
        if(z==u) cpt++;
    }   

    printf("%d",cpt);
    getchar();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop only goes to 1048576, which is 2^20.

Don't you need to loop until 2^40?

Also, note that `int` may not be 40 bits wide.

**Note:**

The naive solution to check all numbers doesn't scale well. Perhaps you should consider a smarter solution?

Answer (score 2):

Because only one number in the range [0, 1048576) has exactly as many bits 1 as 0, when counted in your 40 "bit" array.

The flaw in your logic is that you do not examine all numbers in a given range. For instance, when you want to examine all 40-bit integers, you need to iterate until 2^40 and not 2^20.

Lastly, this brute force solution won't work very well for your problem. Instead, try to consider the pattern that appears when you examine the number of paths from the top-left node and proceeding to the down or right for a small array on a piece of paper. Does one emerge? If you're math-inclined, you will instantly recognise it; otherwise, take a minute to look through the [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the main thing that is wrong is the algorithm you are using (exhaustive search); you would need to loop from 0 to 2<sup>40</sup>-1 to iterate across the entire set of numbers to be tested (rather than to 2<sup>20</sup>-1), which would be an impractical number of iterations, not least as there are faster ways.

Consider the maths of the problem: you want a 40 bit field, with 20 bits set to 1. So, you are choosing 20 things from 40. Think about the <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub> (combination operator from permutations and combinations); that will give you the link to the binomial coefficients. Now think how you might write an algorithm to go through every combination.

Your code would also be more comprehensible if it did not have single letter variable names, and had some comments explaining what it was meant to be doing.

If you are having difficulty remembering the bit width of integer types, I suggest you use

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

and use types like `int64_t` which is guaranteed to be 64 bits. See:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html

(Note that OP apparently wanted a list of the numbers with 20 bits set, rather just the count of such numbers, so merely looking at binomial coefficients is insufficient).

Comment: +1: Looks like a good answer to me. Even better with the note about code quality.

Answer (score -1):

try using a long long int:

```
unsigned long long int a;
```

to fasten and clear a lot of code try also using popcount, it's a function that returns the number of 1-bits in x: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html.
//I'm not 100% sure if the popcount will work with long long ints, but you can try.

BTW I have a question about the same euler problem @: [Binary numbers with the same quantity of 0s and 1s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522417/binary-numbers-with-the-same-quantity-of-0s-and-1s)